# trouble installing phpmyadmin in amazon linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am installing a LAMP enviornment using [amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

I enabled `epel` after that when i try to install `phpmyadmin` using command
`sudo yum install -y phpMyAdmin`. It installs something maybe `phpmyadmin` but in the end it shows some errors like this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-process conflicts with php-process-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

After that when I run this command

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/your_ip_address/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

it shows

```
sed: can't read /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf: No such file or directory
```

what is the solution?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following to resolve the conflict. Basically we will downgrade to php5. Unless your application specifically needs php7, this should be fine. To this this use.

```
sudo yum remove httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
```

Then

```
sudo yum install httpd24 php56 mysql56-server php56-mysqlnd
```

For the second error make sure Apache is installed.

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

You might have to reinstall phpmyadmin after this so it can the virtual host file phpmyadmin.conf

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok the first error was gone but the second one is still there that says sed: can't read /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: I have update the answer for you. Basically that file doesn't exist. After you have installed Apache and phpMyAdmin (in that order) you can search for `sudo find / -name phpmyadmin.conf` and is should be there. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: this file does exist in folder etc/httpd/conf.d  but when i try to edit the file by using ftp i.e changing the ip address from 127.0.0.1 to my ip address (as shown on whatismyip.com) it says you can't edit the file. i am logged in as ec2-user and in the file properties it is showing read and write permission to user. i dont know what's the problem. its urgent c'mon i need to find the solution ASAP

Comment: how can i do it? please explain

Comment: try `sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: it opens a blank file , i dont know commands to edit or insert . but when i open it using winscp there is content in the file but i am not able to change it as i am logged in as ec2 user not as root

Comment: hmm from ec2 user try `sudo su` then use nano as it is easier to edit (shows you the commands needed) `nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` If it is still blank, copy the contents from the other file (the one in ftp).

Comment: can't just simply copy paste and it shows blank file in editor too

Comment: You can definitely copy and paste. Alternatively use scp to move it across or the ftp.